# I pressed P and I don't know what happened

Tags: shortcut

Yesterday I was making a model. There was something that I needed to put on another layer. I forgot the layer shortcut, so I was pressing random letters until I pressed (Ctrl +?) P and it changed the lighting and completely froze. I left it on for a while to see if it would unfreeze, no luck. Today I opened my PC and all I can see in the blender window is my viewport surrounded by black. I really don't wanna close blender since I didn't save my model.

P.S. It is still responding but I can't do anything with it.

Comment: Were you in "Blender Game" engine mode? Did you try to press the "Esc" key?

Comment: A few hints: 1- Try using  ESC to get out of trouble when getting to the wrong tool. 2- Don't press random keys, but the ones you know what they do. 3- The shortcut to move things to a new layer is M (as in Move to layer) followed by the layer number. 4. When you don't know a shortcut use the menu or press the space bar and type something like "layer" and you'll be presented with options. 5.- Most importantly: SAVE YOUR WORK OFTEN, that way if you mess up you can go back to a previous version and not lose a lot of work/time.

Comment: There could be saved temporary versions of the file, located (if Windows) in `user folder/AppData/Local/Temp` (by default).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>P</kbd> used to be the key to start game mode.  I think they unbound it in recent versions to prevent people from having this problem.  (yes, I also fell victim to that once; and the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> toggle).

I agree with all the comments suggesting the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key as a possible remedy.  (although it won't get you back from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>; another <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does).

Comment: `P` does not start the game engine unless the Render Engine is set to Blender Game indeed. `Shift`+`Space` can also be undone using the *Back to Previous* button in the Info area.